# Django using modals for deleting a user

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, bootstrap-modal

I want to delete users with modals in django. I have a deletion function which I don't know how I should return to template.

views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='admin_signin')
@admin_only
def admin_profiles_deletion(request, username):
    context = {}
    account = Account.objects.get(username=username)
    account.delete()
    messages.success(request, "User deleted!")
    context['account'] = account

    return render(request, 'HOW SHOULD I REFER MODALS HERE?', context)
```

And my `urls.py` looks:

```
path('admin/profile/<str:username>/delete', views.admin_profiles_deletion, name='admin_profiles_deletion'),
```

And finally my template is:

```
<td class="text-center td-actions">
   <a href="{% url 'admin_view_profiles' account.username %}"><i class="la la-eye view"></i></a>
   <a href="{% url 'admin_profiles_general_edition' account.username %}"><i class="la la-edit edit"></i></a>
   <a href="{% url 'admin_profiles_deletion' account.username %}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteaccount">
       <i class="la la-close delete"></i>
   </a>
   <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="deleteaccount" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteaccountTitle" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
           <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                   <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteaccountTitle">Delete confirmation</h5>
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                   </button>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                  <h5>Do you want to delete?</h5>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                   <div class="col-6 text-left">
                      <div class="previous">
                          <form method="POST">
                               {% csrf_token %}
                               <input class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" value="Yes">
                          </form>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-6 text-left">
                       <div class="next">
                           <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block" href="{% url 'accounts' %}">No</a>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </td>
```

In modal I want to hit `YES` and then delete specific account. but I don't know how to do it while I am using modals.

Comment: Do you want to use ajax (without refreshing page)? Or do you just want returns to list of users? What error do you get?

Comment: Thank you, I am not using ajax. This is all I have in my html file and and `urls.py` and `views.py`. By hitting `YES` answer I want to delete specific user(account.username).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
...
def admin_profiles_deletion(request, username):
    ...

    return redirect("/admin/profile/")

    # or to return to same (previous) page:
    return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

In your template add `action` attribute to your form

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'admin_profiles_deletion' account.username %}">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" value="Yes">
</form>
```

**OR** to update `action` attribute dynamically

```
<a href="#" data-url="{% url 'admin_profiles_deletion' account.username %}" class="deleteaccount">
    <i class="la la-close delete"></i>
</a>
```

and than with `jQuery`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.deleteaccount').on( "click", function() {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('#deleteaccount form').attr('action', $(this).data("url"));
       $('#deleteaccount').modal('show');
    });
});
</script>
```

---

**UPDATE** - working example http://jsfiddle.net/cbzmewhq/1/

Add `<span id="current_username"></span>?` to your modal body.

Then with `jQuery` add your your desired text on click:
`$('#deleteaccount #current_username').text($(this).data("username"));`

BELOW IS AN EXAMPLE OF YOUR CODE

```
...<!-- YOUR TABLE -->
<td class="text-center td-actions">
  <a href="{% url 'admin_view_profiles' account.username %}"><i class="la la-eye view"></i></a>
  <a href="{% url 'admin_profiles_general_edition' account.username %}"><i class="la la-edit edit"></i></a>
  <a href="#" data-username="{{ account.username }}" data-url="{% url 'admin_profiles_deletion' account.username %}" class="deleteaccount">
    <i class="la la-close delete"></i>
  </a>
</td>
....<!-- YOUR TABLE -->


<!-- Modal  OUT OF TABLE -->
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteaccount" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteaccountTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
           <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteaccountTitle">Delete confirmation</h5>
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- ADD SPAN TO ADD USERNAME dynamically -->
        <h5>Do you want to delete <span id="current_username"></span>?</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-6 text-left">
          <div class="previous">
            <form method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" value="Yes">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-left">
          <div class="next">
            <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block" href="{% url 'accounts' %}">No</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- ADD BELOW CODE TO THE BOTTOM OF BODY -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.deleteaccount').on( "click", function() {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('#deleteaccount form').attr('action', $(this).data("url"));
       $('#deleteaccount #current_username').text($(this).data("username"));
       $('#deleteaccount').modal('show');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ok but in this way the user is not deleted. My modal is not viewing `admin_profiles_deletion` function.

Comment: @M.J, ok, now I understand your question))) I have updated my answer. You can open `modal` with `jQuery` and change `action` attribute dynamically.

Comment: Great, I added attribute `action ` but whenever I want to delete a user it deletes the latest one. not referred one :)

Comment: I mean `Do you want to delete {{account.username}}?` always refers to the latest user. in modal tags but prints true `username` before `<!-- Modal -->`.

Comment: @M.J, This is another one question))). I added your code to my answer. This should work for you.

Comment: Thank you but this way When I put the cursor on deletion button it shows me `#` sign and when I hit it, doesn't happen

Comment: Is a modal popup opening? Do you see the desired username?

Comment: @M.J, see working example [http://jsfiddle.net/cbzmewhq/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/cbzmewhq/1/). Add jQuery script to the bottom of `body` html tag, after `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js`. That must be working.